# PHP/Maths Percentage of Percentage

Tags: php, math

I am working out what the changes of a horse winning a race is from the previous records of each horses.

Horse 1 has won 5% of his races

Horse 2 has won 7% of his races

Horse 3 has won 12% of his races

Now if 3 horses are running in this final race, how do I split 100% between these 3 horses?

Comment: `what the changes of a horse winning a race is` do you mean "what the chances are"? `Now if 3 horses are running in this final race` do you mean "these 3 horses"? Are there no other horses? What does the past records have to do with the final race? What does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this I guess :

**5 + 7 + 12 = 24**

**Horse 1 :**

5 * 100 / 24 = 20.83

**Horse 2 :**

7 * 100 / 24 = 29.17

**Horse 3 :**

12 * 100 / 24 = 50

(20.83 + 29.17 + 50 = 100)